# Erro com laravel passport no heroku

Tags: laravel, api, password

Fiz o deploy de uma aplicação no heroku e estou recebendo o seguinte erro

"message": "Key path \"file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key\" does not exist or is not readable",
    "exception": "LogicException",
    "file": "/app/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php",
    "line": 48,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php",
            "line": 242,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "League\OAuth2\Server\CryptKey",
            "type": "->"
        },

Localmente funciona bem, mas depois do deploy ao fazer um login de usuario que existe no banco de dados era pra ser retornado o token de acesso mas está retornando esse erro. Busquei em outras fontes e testei algumas sujestões, algumas resolveu por enquanto mas ao atulaizar a aplicação e realizar o debug o erro retorna.

Answer (score 0):

Você não mencionou seu código, nem os passos que você utilizou para o deploy.
Você pode tentar isso:

composer require laravel/passport

Registrar config/app.php:

Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,

Run migrations:

php artisan migrate

Por último gerar as keys

php artisan passport:install

Você pode acessar a documentação do heroku também:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oauth